# How to retrieve textview text from main.xml

Tags: android

I have following main.xml of layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

and I am trying to retrieve the text i.e. @string/hello  by using the following code

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



  TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview01);
  String input= tv.getText().toString();

  Log.d("Info",input);
```

but I am not able to see the output. Application is crashing with NULL Exception error at the String input = tv.getText(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

before calling `findViewById`

Comment: Thanks. I got the coding wise but will u elaborate y does we have to call the content view before finding any Id ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: @user1169079 - Until you call `setContentView`, the views defined in your xml are not attached to the activity's window, so there's no view for `findViewById` to find.

Answer (score 2):

Update your activity code as follows,

```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main); // This line is missing in your code.

  TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview01);
  String input= tv.getText().toString();

  Log.d("Info",input);
```

You are actually missing the mapping of xml to Activity.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);


  TextView tv= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview01);
  String input= tv.getText().toString();

  Log.d("Info",input);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have set the view properly

   ```
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
   ```

If this is not done you'll get "tv" variable as null because the view is not loaded.
2. If the above is set then check if "hello" is properly set in `strings.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `NullPointerException` because your reference in tv is null.
You didn't set the Layout i.e. `setLayout(R.layout.main);`

Include the above line after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` and your code will work.